# I am getting category name displayed in each article.How to disable that? 

Tags: joomla2.5

.I am working n Joomla 2.5.4.I have created menu having External URL menu type and linked to child menus with articles.On each article the category name is getting displayed.I tried all settings in Global Configuration.Anyone have idea about it?

Comment: you'll find in article settings, open any article for edit, and check right side options

Comment: Mac,I have tried all that..still category title is coming up

Answer (score 0):

Check Components->Article Manager in the admin site. Then click "Options" in the upper right. There should be an option in the modal that opens to disable category titles.

Comment: Yes.I know that David..and those options are already set to hide.Can u suggest something else?

Comment: Hmm... Can you give me a little more info on this. So you have the external menu item that links to what exactly? Is this a category type display that shows many articles or linking to a particular article that show the category title? Could you add a link to take a look at what is displaying?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is so stupid but I found it finaly - go to Category Manager - inside category Articles change in Basic Options tab to blog. In general article options I set to hide category title and that's it.  ;)